# How to update data as per searching value from table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to update  column value with one data,If that is not present in that column using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

> db_special:

```
 id      name       special  
 1       aaa         1
 2       bbb         6
 3       ccc         1,7
 4      ddd          1,6,7
 5      eee            1
```

Here my condition is little bit complex. I need to update `7` with comma separated to those row which has not value like `7` and `6`. As per my condition the table should looks like below after update.

```
 1      aaa        1,7    
 2      bbb         6    
 3      ccc        1,7    
 4      ddd        1,6,7    
 5      eee        1,7
```

Here as per condition only first and last rows are reflecting. I need query for this so that I can get result as per expected.Please help.

Comment: Relational databases begin with normalisation. So start there.

Comment: Are specials referring to ids on another table?

Comment: @RossWilson : Yes,its id from other table and multiple if one one name are saved as comma separated string.

Comment: I would definitely recommend looking at many-to-many relationships for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like as below:

```
$select = "SELECT special FROM db_special" //select data

while($result) { // go through each loop
    $special = explode(",", $result['special']) ;
    if(!in_array(7, $special) && !in_array(6, $special)) {
        $special_new = (!empty($result['special'])) ? $result['special'].", 7" : "7";
        $query = update db_special SET special = $special_new //update data
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me to test it and let you know.

Comment: I think update query is missing the proper condition.I need to update those rows whose dont have value 7/6.

Comment: `if(!in_array(7, $special) && !in_array(6, $special)) {`  this condition checking both not 6 and not 7 in db

Comment: I think or(||) condition should apply because I dont need update the rows which has 6/7.

Comment: You can update as require. I was thought 6 and 7 should not in table then update